# Is there a way to add white space before and after x-axis in an apex chart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, apexcharts

I need to find a way to add some whitespace before and after a graph in Apex charts.
Currently my graph is displaying at 0,0 and ending at the last data point, see image
[image]

..but what I'd like is to add space before first data point, and after last, see image
[image]

I can't see a setting that does this and I've tried hacking away at it but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can add padding to the sides using grid option

```js
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'


var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'line'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30,40,35,50,49,60,70,91,125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999],
    
  },
  grid: {
    show: true,
    borderColor: '#90A4AE',
    strokeDashArray: 0,
    position: 'back',
    xaxis: {
        lines: {
            show: false
        }
    },   
    yaxis: {
        lines: {
            show: false
        }
    },  
    row: {
        colors: undefined,
        opacity: 0.5
    },  
    column: {
        colors: undefined,
        opacity: 0.5
    },  
    padding: {
        top: 0,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 50
    },  
}
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#app"), options);

chart.render()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anees , that adds padding left and right of the chart, but not to the actual data itself as in my screenshot above.

Comment: oh okay. maybe you can add a bottom border and don't use the default if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Setting `tickPlacement` between worked for me.

```
xaxis: {
      tickPlacement: 'between',
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please 

[edit](/posts/78183825/edit)

your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  I suggest reading some highly voted answers for examples.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).